# GPUImageView flashes between filtered and unfiltered view when adding a GPUImageFilter

Tags: ios, filter, camera, avfoundation, gpuimage

I'm trying to display a `GPUImageView` with a live camera feed (using `GPUImageStillCamera` or `GPUImageVideoCamera`) and display a series of filters below it. When a filter is tapped, I want it to apply that filter to the live feed so that the GPUImageView shows a live, filtered feed of the camera input. I have all of it set up, but for some reason when I tap on pretty much any included `GPUImageOutput` filter (Vignette, Smooth Toon, Emboss, etc), the video feed flashes like crazy. It seems like its alternating between the filtered view and the unfiltered view. When i switch to a different filter, i can tell that the filter is working properly for a tiny tiny fraction of a second before it switches to a different filter.

The grayscale and sepia filters don't flash but instead only show at half-strength. I've tried setting the intensity to 1.0 (and a bunch of other values) for the sepia filter, but the grayscale one doesn't have any settings to change and it seems like some things are gray but there's still color. I tried to take a screenshot of the grayscale view but when i look at the screenshots, the image is either properly grayscaled or not grayscaled at all, even though its not what i see on my actual device. My theory is that its switching between the filtered view and the non-filtered view really fast, therefore creating the illusion of a grayscale filter at 50% strength.

I have no idea why this would be happening, because the standard GPUImage example projects work just fine, and I'm not doing much differently in my project.

If anyone could help me out or at least point me in the right direction, it would be very much appreciated. I have been trying to debug this issue for 3 days straight and I simply cannot figure it out.

EDIT: when I call `capturePhotoAsImageProcessedUpToFilter` on my `GPUImageStillCamera`, it returns `nil` for both the `UIImage` and for the `NSError` in the completion block (even though the `GPUImageStillCamera` is not nil. Not sure if this is related, but I figured it was worth mentioning.

EDIT 2: I just realized it was returning a nil image because no filters were set. But if that's the case, how do you take a photo without having any filters active? And does that possibly have anything to do with my original issue? I set a grayscale filter (and I'm still seeing the half-strength version of it), and the image returned in the completion block is the actual proper grayscale image, despite the fact that the live feed looks different.

Comment: The way you build your filter chain matters: you can use a "pass through" filter (`[[GPUImageFilter alloc] init]`) when no filtering is required, and you should ensure that you remove targets from the input (your live camera feed) before adding the selected filter and the GPUImageView as the filter target again.

Comment: When I create the camera feed, it doesn't have any targets (I assume) so there's nothing to remove before i add any other filters. I tried using a placeholder filter (the passthrough one you mentioned) until I needed to use an actual filter but it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have two inputs targeting your view.

Can't tell without seeing your code, but I found that drawing a graph with all my input / outputs really helped debugging filters.